# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myApp' when using Entity Framework with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, sitefinity

I'm an Entity Framework newbie who is trying to develop some simple add-on to Sitefinity CMS on top of MySql database.

The database is working perfectly with Sitefinity itself; however, when my own EF code trying to connect with it, I always got the error:

```
Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myApp'.
```

The connection string I'm using is:

```
<add connectionString="Server=localhost;Uid=MyUserId;Pwd=MyPassword;Database=dev_MyDatabase;CharacterSet=utf8" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" dbType="MySQL" name="MyDatabase" />
```

The user (id and password) is created in MySQL, thus, when trying putting it in IIS (Application Pools > Advanced Settings...), it says "The specified user name does not exist".

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: try changing your app pool of your application on IIS or change the identity of myApp apppool as mentioned in http://domainwebcenter.com/?p=716

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Entity Framework.

What does your Context look like? If you have a constructor that inherits the base constructor of DbContext, you need to make sure that you pass along the correct name in the parameter. In your case, it should look like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext():
        base("MyDatabase")
    {

    }
}
```